# how can i fake sensor data?

Tags: ros, sensor, data, rosnode

[image: Rosanswers logo]

i wonder ho i can fake sensor data sdi12 serial and write ros node for it. Because i dont have any hardware to work with

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/202292/how-can-i-fake-sensor-data?/) by [dmngu9](https://answers.ros.org/users/21514/dmngu9/) on ROS Answers with karma: 150 on 2015-02-02

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [adolescent](https://answers.ros.org/users/21557/adolescent/) on 2015-02-03**:
you read this data from a bag file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You can find a list of possible sonar messages [here](http://wiki.ros.org/sensor_msgs). Every time you need to publish sensor data you can fill the sensor_msgs fields accordingly. For example parse a .txt or a .csv file.

---

Originally posted by [kokirits](https://answers.ros.org/users/21162/kokirits/) with karma: 290 on 2015-02-03

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1